# R: Conditional cumulative sum/rollover along a column

Tags: r

I have a dataset where I'm trying to explore the impact of capping a variable at a given value and rolling the excess into subsequent intervals. I can conceptually see a few ways to do this with `cumsum()` or similar, but struggling to see how to implement it in a logical way.

The input data isn't huge (10,000s of rows, not into the 100,000s); so efficiency isn't crucial.

Reprex input data:

| interval starting | kWh |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 19:00 | 12.2 |
| 2021-01-01 19:30 | 14.7 |
| 2021-01-01 20:00 | 20.2 |
| 2021-01-01 20:30 | 30.7 |
| 2021-01-01 21:00 | 36.3 |
| 2021-01-01 21:30 | 36.7 |
| 2021-01-01 22:00 | 30.1 |
| 2021-01-01 22:30 | 26.3 |
| 2021-01-01 23:00 | 18.1 |
| 2021-01-01 23:30 | 15.8 |
| 2021-01-02 00:00 | 11.4 |
| 2021-01-02 00:30 | 10.2 |
| 2021-01-02 01:00 | 11.9 |
| 2021-01-02 01:30 | 12.3 |
| 2021-01-02 02:00 | 9.1 |
| 2021-01-02 02:30 | 8.6 |
| 2021-01-02 03:00 | 8.3 |
| 2021-01-02 03:30 | 10.1 |

And what I want to do is limit the value in the kWh column to a maximum 20.0; if the value exceeds that I'd like to roll the excess into the next interval, and then the next and so on, until all of the energy has been account for (so the sum across a wide enough interval is always the same), but the peak is never above the limit.

Desired output:

| interval starting | kWh | limit_kWh |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 19:00 | 12.2 | 12.2 |
| 2021-01-01 19:30 | 14.7 | 14.7 |
| 2021-01-01 20:00 | 20.2 | 20.0 |
| 2021-01-01 20:30 | 30.7 | 20.0 |
| 2021-01-01 21:00 | 36.3 | 20.0 |
| 2021-01-01 21:30 | 36.7 | 20.0 |
| 2021-01-01 22:00 | 30.1 | 20.0 |
| 2021-01-01 22:30 | 26.3 | 20.0 |
| 2021-01-02 23:00 | 18.1 | 20.0 |
| 2021-01-02 23:30 | 15.8 | 20.0 |
| 2021-01-02 00:00 | 11.4 | 20.0 |
| 2021-01-02 00:30 | 10.2 | 20.0 |
| 2021-01-02 01:00 | 11.9 | 20.0 |
| 2021-01-02 01:30 | 12.3 | 20.0 |
| 2021-01-02 02:00 | 9.1 | 20.0 |
| 2021-01-02 02:30 | 8.6 | 17.7 |
| 2021-01-02 03:00 | 8.3 | 8.3 |
| 2021-01-02 03:30 | 10.1 | 10.1 |

So in this the total amount of energy is the same over the time period, but the peak energy is never above the specified limit.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

This is just a basic loop that does what you want. It is not particularly efficient, but I couldn't figure out a good way to make it faster using vectorization.

```r
overflow <- 0
for (i in 1:nrow(d)) {
  if (d$kWh[i] + overflow > 20) {
    d$limit_kWh[i] <- 20
    overflow <- d$kWh[i] + overflow - 20
  }
  else {
    d$limit_kWh[i] <- d$kWh[i] + overflow
    overflow <- 0
  }
}
```

Basically the amount above 20, if any, is stored in the `overflow` variable, which updates at each entry.

---

Actually, here is an approximately 2x faster method that relies more on vectorization. It involves creating an `overflow` vector that contains the amount of overflow from the previous date.

```
overflow <- numeric(nrow(d))
for (i in 2:nrow(d)) {
  overflow[i] <- max(d$kWh[i-1] + overflow[i-1] - 20, 0)
}
d$limit_kWh <- pmin(d$kWh + overflow, 20)
```

Comment: Thank you! This works wonderfully, I used the vectorized version. Speed was more than acceptable (quite fast) for my initial dataset of ~8,000 rows. Will utilise it on some larger datasets later.

Answer (score 2):

A way will be to use `Reduce` with `accumulate`. The method is identical with the answer given by @Noah.

```
x$limit_kWh <- pmin(20, x$kWh + head(Reduce(function(x, y)
    {max(0, x + y - 20)}, x$kWh, 0, accumulate = TRUE), -1))
x
#   interval starting  kWh limit_kWh
#1   2021-01-01 19:00 12.2      12.2
#2   2021-01-01 19:30 14.7      14.7
#3   2021-01-01 20:00 20.2      20.0
#4   2021-01-01 20:30 30.7      20.0
#5   2021-01-01 21:00 36.3      20.0
#6   2021-01-01 21:30 36.7      20.0
#7   2021-01-01 22:00 30.1      20.0
#8   2021-01-01 22:30 26.3      20.0
#9   2021-01-01 23:00 18.1      20.0
#10  2021-01-01 23:30 15.8      20.0
#11  2021-01-02 00:00 11.4      20.0
#12  2021-01-02 00:30 10.2      20.0
#13  2021-01-02 01:00 11.9      20.0
#14  2021-01-02 01:30 12.3      20.0
#15  2021-01-02 02:00  9.1      20.0
#16  2021-01-02 02:30  8.6      17.7
#17  2021-01-02 03:00  8.3       8.3
#18  2021-01-02 03:30 10.1      10.1
```

Data:

```
x <- read.table(header = TRUE, check.names =  FALSE,
                text = '"interval starting"     kWh
"2021-01-01 19:00"  12.2
"2021-01-01 19:30"  14.7
"2021-01-01 20:00"  20.2
"2021-01-01 20:30"  30.7
"2021-01-01 21:00"  36.3
"2021-01-01 21:30"  36.7
"2021-01-01 22:00"  30.1
"2021-01-01 22:30"  26.3
"2021-01-01 23:00"  18.1
"2021-01-01 23:30"  15.8
"2021-01-02 00:00"  11.4
"2021-01-02 00:30"  10.2
"2021-01-02 01:00"  11.9
"2021-01-02 01:30"  12.3
"2021-01-02 02:00"  9.1
"2021-01-02 02:30"  8.6
"2021-01-02 03:00"  8.3
"2021-01-02 03:30"  10.1')
```

Comment: Nice one-line answer!

Answer (score 1):

I took @Noah's basic logic and put it into a datastep().  It is the same result, and no more efficient than the for loop.  But it is somewhat easier to read.

Here is the input data:

```
# Input data
dt <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = '
interval_starting   kWh
"2021-01-01 19:00"  12.2
"2021-01-01 19:30"  14.7
"2021-01-01 20:00"  20.2
"2021-01-01 20:30"  30.7
"2021-01-01 21:00"  36.3
"2021-01-01 21:30"  36.7
"2021-01-01 22:00"  30.1
"2021-01-01 22:30"  26.3
"2021-01-01 23:00"  18.1
"2021-01-01 23:30"  15.8
"2021-01-02 00:00"  11.4
"2021-01-02 00:30"  10.2
"2021-01-02 01:00"  11.9
"2021-01-02 01:30"  12.3
"2021-01-02 02:00"  9.1
"2021-01-02 02:30"  8.6
"2021-01-02 03:00"  8.3
"2021-01-02 03:30"  10.1')
```

Here is the datastep:

```
library(libr)

# Run datastep
res <- datastep(dt, 
                retain = list(overflow = 0),
                calculate = {limit = 20},
                drop = c("limit", "overflow"),
    {
  
      if (kWh + overflow > limit) {

        limit_kWh  <- limit
        overflow <- kWh + overflow - limit
        
      } else {
        
        limit_kWh <- kWh + overflow
        overflow <- 0
      }
  
    })
```

Here are the results:

```
# View results
res
#    interval_starting  kWh limit_kWh
# 1   2021-01-01 19:00 12.2      12.2
# 2   2021-01-01 19:30 14.7      14.7
# 3   2021-01-01 20:00 20.2      20.0
# 4   2021-01-01 20:30 30.7      20.0
# 5   2021-01-01 21:00 36.3      20.0
# 6   2021-01-01 21:30 36.7      20.0
# 7   2021-01-01 22:00 30.1      20.0
# 8   2021-01-01 22:30 26.3      20.0
# 9   2021-01-01 23:00 18.1      20.0
# 10  2021-01-01 23:30 15.8      20.0
# 11  2021-01-02 00:00 11.4      20.0
# 12  2021-01-02 00:30 10.2      20.0
# 13  2021-01-02 01:00 11.9      20.0
# 14  2021-01-02 01:30 12.3      20.0
# 15  2021-01-02 02:00  9.1      20.0
# 16  2021-01-02 02:30  8.6      17.7
# 17  2021-01-02 03:00  8.3       8.3
# 18  2021-01-02 03:30 10.1      10.1
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not familiar with `datastep()`, is it similar to dplyr's `rowwise()`?

Comment: Yes, it is a similar idea.  Except inside the { } you can nest conditionals as deep as you want.  The "retain" does the same thing as a lag().